# Elasticsearch ranking issue

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, pyes

I am facing a strange but odd issue in Elasticsearch ranking results.

The problem is Elasticsearch results are not consistent.

For the same set of documents and query, Elasticsearch is returning different answers !!
The first 10 results are always the same for the query but vary from thereafter.

How can this be rectified?

```
results = self.conn.search(query=some_query, explain=True, search_type="dfs_query_then_fetch")
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "my_mapping": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "\\u0091=>\\u0027",
                        "\\u0092=>\\u0027",
                        "\\u2018=>\\u0027",
                        "\\u2019=>\\u0027",
                        "\\u201B=>\\u0027"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "english_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords": "_english_"
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "wsplusstop": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": "my_mapping",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "english_stop",
                        "porter_stem"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tools and versions used:

Python : 2.7, 
Pyes : 0.99.6, 
Elasticsearch : 5.4.3

Comment: We're gonna need some more info. What queries did you run? What mappings to you have? What is your analysis chain

Comment: @aclokay added the mapping

Comment: Do you index new documents while testing your query?

Comment: used same set of documents and query. I guess the issue is with shards.  When set to 1 the results are consistent. But is that the right way?

Comment: weird, Lucene is near-real time, does it happen all of the time or just for the first moments, just untill the indexes are committed?

Comment: each time this is happening. will shards have any effects on ranking?